# ruby on Rails 3 and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am new to rails and have been working thru a number of tutorials.  I have a controller with the following actions:  Contact and Home.  The routes.rb has the following:

SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/contact"

# The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
Everything else in the standard routes is commented

When I try to reach the page http://localhost:3000/pages/home

I get

Routing Error

No route matches "/pages/home"

on the web page.

I restarted the rails server and checked routes with rake routes - results below

pages_home GET /pages/home(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
pages_contact GET /pages/contact(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}

I tried other tutorials that were based on 2.3 version of rails and had lots of routing issues but was running 3.0 instead so went to 3.0 tutorial.  Same routing issues.  I even have the same problem when I put a static page "hello world" in the public folder.  According to tutorial, that should just come up but I get same routing error message.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.  A real noob mistake.  Running rails, it is important to be in the right directory.  I was in a previous example directory so the routes I needed were not there.

Comment: Hehe we are all noob sometimes ... ;)